# require('os').tmpdir() returns 2 different results

Tags: node.js

I'm facing an strange issue. I have tried to find the solution to fix, but I still cannot find out.

I use the code in my application

> require('os').tmpdir()

it returns the current workspace folder /srv/workspace/

> node -e "console.log(require('os').tmpdir())"

It returns /tmp

The issue happens on Virtual Machine and server. It doesn't happen on my main machine.

Node: v5.7.1

npm: 3.9.5

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you share the platform and version you are working on?

Comment: Does your app run under a different os user?

Answer (score 5):

The value of `os.tmpdir()` is determined by the `TMPDIR` or `TMP` environment variables (`TEMP` on Windows).

It's likely something is changing that environment variable when you run your application.

You'll have to investigate to see if it's in your code or a library that you use.

Print out the value of each environment variable to see which one has been overridden:

`console.log('TMPDIR=', process.env.TMPDIR);
console.log('TMP=', process.env.TMP);
console.log('TEMP=', process.env.TEMP);`

Comment: Added the console log and got the result

TMPDIR= <work-space-path>
TMP= undefined
TEMP= undefined

Checked `echo $TMPDIR`, got `/tmp`

Comment: And I tried to run `node -e "console.log(process.env.TMPDIR)"`, return /tmp

Comment: You'll need to search through your project (or npm modules) and find where TEMPDIR variable is being set to your workspace path.

Comment: Even though I set TMPDIR variable by using `export TMPDIR=/tmp`. however, when running the code `require('os').tmpdir()` still return `undefined`

Comment: Check your javascript code and modules to see if anything is changing the TMPDIR environment variable **in node**. Changing the `export TMPDIR=...` in your shell won't fix things if the problem is in the javascript code.

Comment: Hey, what 'word' can I use to search in code to make sure there's no code change the temp dir location in node?

Comment: I'd do a case-insensitive search for those three environment variables

Comment: I have done `export TMPDIR=` by supervisor and I try to run the test on my terminal (after ssh into VirtualMachine)
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-precise-64:~$ node -e "console.log(process.env.TMPDIR)"
undefined
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-precise-64:~$ node -e "console.log(require('os').tmpdir())"
/tmp

Comment: Sorry @Sly_cardinal, I cannot join the chat, looks like it's caused by my reputation is less than 20, Stackoverflow doesn't allow to use the chat.

Comment: From those issues it looks like you're hitting a bug when running node as root - it's clearing the env variables. You might need to write your own little module to normalise the behaviour and return the correct temp directory in that situation - i.e. detect if the environment variable has been cleared and return the correct temp directory.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that way